# MessageSecurityException: Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message

Tags: wcf, web-services, ssl, xamarin.android

What is the state of Mono for Android's secure WCF services? Is it up to SOAP 1.2 yet? 
I am writing a POC for an Android app that will interact with WCF services, but am struggling to get the thing working.

I am trying to connect to a service that has `TransportWithMessageCredential` security. However I am getting an error on the server side.

This is the server side error:

> MessageSecurityException: Security processor was unable to find a
>   security header in the message. This might be because the message is
>   an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the
>   communicating parties. This can occur if the service is configured for
>   security and the client is not using security.

Server Config:

```xml
<service name="BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Services.UI.Products.Specifications.IngredientService" 
         behaviorConfiguration="CredentialValidation">
    <endpoint address="/BasicHttp"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BDBasicHttpBindingWithSecurity" 
        contract="BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Services.UI.Products.Specifications.IIngredientService" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
</service>

<behavior name="CredentialValidation">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  <HttpStatusCode200Behavior />
  <serviceCredentials type="BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Security.Authentication.PasswordServiceCredentials, BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Security, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
      customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Security.CredentialValidator, BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Security" />
  </serviceCredentials>
</behavior>

<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="HttpStatusCode200Behavior" type="BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Services.Common.ServiceModel.HttpStatusCode200BehaviorExtension, BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Services.Common" />
  </behaviorExtensions>

  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BDBasicHttpBindingWithSecurity" messageEncoding="Text" maxReceivedMessageSize="655536">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</extensions>
```

Client Code:

```cs
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    private Button button;
    const string address = "https://.../IngredientService.svc/BasicHttp";

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);


        var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential)
        {
            MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text,
            Security =
            {
                Transport =
                {
                    ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None,
                    ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None
                },
                Message =
                {
                    ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName,
                }
            },
            HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 655536,
            ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
            {
                MaxArrayLength = 655536,
                MaxStringContentLength = 655536,
            },
            SendTimeout = timeout,
            OpenTimeout = timeout,
            ReceiveTimeout = timeout,
        };

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += OnServerCertificateValidationCallback;

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += delegate
        {
            client = new IngredientServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(address));
            var clientCredential = client.ClientCredentials.UserName;
            clientCredential.UserName = "admin";
            clientCredential.Password = "KDNSG7";

            client.BeginGetIngredients("e", callBack, null);
        };
    }

    IngredientServiceClient client;

    private void callBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var result = client.EndGetIngredients(ar);

        button.Text = result.First().Name;
    }

    private bool OnServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, 
                                                       X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This code works fine in WPF, the result is returned and all is well. I see from older threads that the WCF is still early in the development cycle, but I just want to check if maybe I am doing something wrong first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used RestSharp and a custom authentication header contents that would be authenticated on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

To enable your service to work despite the binding mismatch you need to modify the

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" enableUnsecuredResponse="true"  >
   <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
 </security>
```

I've included the whole webconfig from the example above with the added change

```
 <service name="BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Services.UI.Products.Specifications.IngredientService" 
         behaviorConfiguration="CredentialValidation">
    <endpoint address="/BasicHttp"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BDBasicHttpBindingWithSecurity" 
        contract="BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Services.UI.Products.Specifications.IIngredientService" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
</service>

<behavior name="CredentialValidation">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  <HttpStatusCode200Behavior />
  <serviceCredentials type="BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Security.Authentication.PasswordServiceCredentials, BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Security, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
      customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Security.CredentialValidator, BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Security" />
  </serviceCredentials>
</behavior>

<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="HttpStatusCode200Behavior" type="BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Services.Common.ServiceModel.HttpStatusCode200BehaviorExtension, BrandDirector.ApplicationServer.Core.Services.Common" />
  </behaviorExtensions>

  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BDBasicHttpBindingWithSecurity" messageEncoding="Text" maxReceivedMessageSize="655536">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" enableUnsecuredResponse="true"  >
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</extensions>
```

Comment: Note that enableUnsecuredResponse does not work with basicHttpBinding. It works on customBinding, though.

Answer (score 2):

At this time MonoTouch does not support the WS-Security Protocol, which allows clients to send credentials inside the SOAP message envelope. However, MonoTouch does support the ability to send HTTP Basic Authentication credentials to the server by specifying the appropriate ClientCredentialType.

See this page:
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/guides/Application_Fundamentals/Introduction_to_Web_Services

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding the service in a audienceUris tag in the host config file fixed the issue with the same exception.

```
<system.identityModel>
...
    <identityConfiguration>
    ...
        <audienceUris>
            <add value="serviceName.svc" />
        </audienceUris>
    ...
    </identityConfiguration>
...
</system.identityModel>
```